# Applying MAX on COUNT with sub queries and JOIN | SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, max

I'm trying to list the projects with the highest number of employees assigned to work on it.

This lists only the top number of employees on a given project...

```
SELECT MAX(number_employees)
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(a.employee_id) AS number_employees
    FROM assignment a
    JOIN project p
    ON p.project_id = a.project_id
    GROUP BY a.project_id, p.project_name);
```

And this list all projects with the number of employees...

```
    
SELECT a.project_id, p.project_name, COUNT(a.employee_id) AS number_employees
    FROM assignment a
    JOIN project p
    ON p.project_id = a.project_id
    GROUP BY a.project_id, p.project_name;
```

However, I'm trying to list all projects but only the projects with the highest number of employees on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your first query with `FETCH` clause as follows:

```
SELECT a.project_id, p.project_name, COUNT(a.employee_id) AS number_employees
 FROM assignment a
 JOIN project p ON p.project_id = a.project_id
GROUP BY a.project_id, p.project_name
order by number_employees desc
fetch first 1 row WITH TIES
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the problem is there is more than 1 project with the same max amount of employees. I could increase the number of rows it fetches I suppose but wondering if there is a cleaner way?

Comment: Ok, Use `WITH TIES` as updated in the answer and this is most easiest and cleaner way then using the analytical function. If you want more project then you just need to change in the `fetch first 1 row WITH TIES`

Comment: You can accept this answer if you think it resolved your issue